# How to see if number in column from file1 is between numbers from columns in file2 using Bash - nested loops?

Tags: bash, loops, awk, comparison, nested

I would like to do the following in the bash command line...

I have 2 files. File1 looks like.

```
585 1504    13  10000   10468   ID1
585 3612    114 10468   11447   ID2
585 437     133 11503   11675   ID1
```

File2 looks like.

```
400220  10311    10311 
400220  11490    11490 
400220  11923    11923
```

for each number in File2 column 2, I would like to know if it is between any of the number pairs in File1 columns 4 and 5 And create File3.txt with the output as follows...

If yes, I want to write column 2 from File2 and column 6 from File1 to File3.
If no, I want to write column 2 from File2 and the string "NoID" to File3.
So for the example data File3.txt should look like so.

```
10311   ID1
11490   NoID
11923   NoID
```

I am used to working in Python and in there would write a script using a nested for loops and if statements, but would prefer to use Bash for this (of which I am still a relative beginner). It seems to me that using a similar nested loop approach combined with awk and other conditional statements could be the way to go. can anyone suggest good ideas with maybe example syntax?

NB. The actual files contain over 3 million rows data

Cheers muchly in advance

Comment: Bash is not compiled, it is interpreted. I would stay with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{f[NR]=$4;l[NR]=$5;id[NR]=$6;next}{for(i in id){if($2>f[i]&&$2<l[i]){printf "%-8s%s\n",$2,id[i];next}}printf "%-8s%s\n",$2,"NoID"}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
10311   ID1
11490   NoID
11923   NoID
```

Comment: Thank you very much @konsolebox, works great, took me time to understand and modify it for the specifics. Below I have added a couple of extras, placing a tab between the $2 and the ID and also how to write it to file3 as opposed to printing to stdout. > awk 'NR==FNR{f[NR]=$4;l[NR]=$5;id[NR]=$6;next}{for(i in id){if($2>f[i]&&$2<l[i]){printf "%-8s%s\n",$2"\t",id[i] > "file3" ;next}}printf "%-8s%s\n",$2"\t","NoID" > "file3"}' file1 file2

Comment: @TomSmith I see although you could just have redirected it as a whole instead: `awk 'NR==FNR{f[NR]=$4;l[NR]=$5;id[NR]=$6;next}{for(i in id){if($2>f[i]&&$2<l[i]){printf "%-8s%s\n",$2"\t",id[i];next}}printf "%-8s%s\n",$2"\t","NoID"}' file1 file2 > file3`

Comment: i attempted that first but to no avail, reading some documentation seemed to suggest that redirecting it to file had to be done within the awk text, hence redirecting each printf independently, but maybe I am missing something.